# Problems of executing a block of code asynchronously in play framework

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using amazon s3 to upload photos as my service.
According to http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ThreadPools , the code must be blocking code.

"when your code may block include:
Using REST/WebService APIs through a 3rd party client library (ie, not using Play’s asynchronous WS API)".

"Note that you may be tempted to therefore wrap your blocking code in Futures. This does not make it non blocking, it just means the blocking will happen in a different thread. You still need to make sure that the thread pool that you are using there has enough threads to handle the blocking."

But now my code is :

```
return async(
    future(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
            return OP.upload(Req, name); //upload phoho with s3
        }   
     }).map(new F.Function<String,Result>() {
         public Result apply(String i) {
            return ok(i);
         }
     })
```

So is it equal to the code below? (cause i am using a WebService APIs through a 3rd party client library)

```
     return OP.upload(Req, name);
```

Will there be any problems if I still use async methods?

I ask that because my server have crushed some times. 
the dump info is:

```
 "application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-231" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc994101000 nid=0x5964 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fc9f6608000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:394)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:182)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:163)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:710)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:238)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
- locked <0x0000000715dd6038> (a sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
- locked <0x0000000715dd6038> (a sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader)
  ...
```

We can see that resource <0x0000000715dd6038> is locked. On the same time, all the other thread are waiting for this resource. Then the system stucked. Is the problem caused by forcing blocking code running in ascy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're wrapping the blocking call is correct, this is not causing the issue (but maybe the 3rd party client library is causing issues).
Regarding the S3 communication, I recommend to use a non-blocking/async api, e.g. [jclouds](http://www.jclouds.org) has async operations (you then need to convert the java Future to a play Promise), or try to just use play's WS.

Comment: And is it the same just using return OP.upload(Req, name) instead of the async one? If I still use the 3rd lib of amazons3.

Comment: No, it's better to wrap it with future+async as documented by the page (ThreadPools) you mentioned. If you don't use future+async you'd have to reconfigure the default thread pool.